# Where is my $_FILES['temp_name'] being set? -angularjs app

Tags: php, angularjs

This has been bugging me for hours now..

I am writing an application with angularjs, and trying to get the php side of the file upload working.

it seems that the php script is trying to copy the file from /tmp/randomuniquefilename to the correct directory. The issue being I don't want it to be stored in my root temp folder at all. I have changed the PHP.ini default file upload path to /var/www/tmp/ the /var/www/tmp/ folder exists and has the correct permissions.

I would like to know how/where my `$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ]` variable is being set so I can change it.. I did previously try simply `$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ] = '/var/www/tmp/'` this didn't work for me.

My php error:

> [Tue Jan 07 15:46:14 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/funandgames/jobernize/uploaded/bleg.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/funandgames/jobernize/uploaded/test.php on line 18, referer: `http://127.0.0.1/funandgames/jobernize/`
>
> [Tue Jan 07 15:46:14 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpbkz0xn' to '/var/www/funandgames/jobernize/uploaded/bleg.png' in /var/www/funandgames/jobernize/uploaded/test.php on line 18, referer: `http://127.0.0.1/funandgames/jobernize/`

Could it be my js setting that var, or would it be PHP?

Here is my php:

```
<?php

if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    
    function varDumpToString ($var)
    {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($var);
        $result = ob_get_clean();
        error_log($result);
    }

    varDumpToString($_FILES);

    $tempPath = '/var/www' . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];

    error_log($tempPath);

    move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );

    $answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
    $json = json_encode( $answer );

    echo $json;

} else {

    echo 'No files';

}

?>
```

I just appended /var/www to the path, and now I am not getting any errors, but nothing is happening, the file is not being copied.

Seems that temp name includes /tmp/ not just a file name for some reason, is this normal?

Comment: Did you restart the web server after making changes to `php.ini`? FYI, the `tmp_name` is set server-side and your *permission denied* error has nothing to do with the source file but the destination path

Comment: yes I did, and yeah I know thanks, haven't got around to dealing with the destination path, just want to get the correct source path.

Comment: Check what `phpinfo()` shows for the [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) setting. Also, `tmp_name` will contain a full path. You don't prefix it with anything

Comment: ok so `tmp_name` is set by default? ill do that now thanks

Comment: Yes, typically the first argument to `move_uploaded_file()` is simply `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`. Also note from the manual - *"If the directory specified here (`upload_tmp_dir`) is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory."*. This may explain what you're seeing. There's also nothing wrong with using the system tmp dir if it's available

Comment: hmm okay, so I realised that I had actually changed my cli php.ini file, this time I changed the one under apache2, after restarting the server I am getting `no value` for `upload_tmp_dir`, I tried wrapping it with and without quotes.

EDIT: forgot to remove `;`, php ini is now showing the right dir, will try the script again now

Comment: $_FILES['tmp_name'] is still returning `/tmp/phporD4g5`...

Comment: That probably means the path in `upload_tmp_dir` is not writeable so it's reverting to the system default. Again, there's nothing wrong with this. Why is it a problem?

Comment: Its more a matter of preference, also recall having a permission issue with the system default, I dont think my user has write access to it without sudo.

My permissions are : `drwxr-xr-x  2 will will 4096 Jan  7 15:45 tmp` apache is also owned by `will`...

Comment: Obviously your script has write access to `/tmp`, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing files there. Who is the owner of the files being uploaded into `/tmp` (like `/tmp/phporD4g5`)? Also, it's very odd to run Apache as a non-system user

Comment: How could the files being uploaded have an owner if they are uploaded from a browser? Also, looks like i dont need to sudo in tmp, however i'm not really interested in using the root tmp, even if it may be the simplest solution, really I just want to know why my non-default tmp is not working :/

apache and my non-def tmp are both owned by the same user and it has write permissions, so why would it be reverting to the default tmp

Comment: I think perhaps you're not aware of how file uploads are handled server-side. The browser sends the file data to your server where it is saved by the server-side process (PHP) to the path specified in `upload_tmp_dir`. The user executing that process will be the owner of that temporary file and thus, requires write access to the temporary upload path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44669/discussion-between-phil-and-melbourne2991)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the permission of tmp_file_upload to 755 Following is the command chmod -R 755 tmp_file_upload

This is because `images` and `tmp_file_upload` are only writable by `root` user. For upload to work we need to make the owner of those folders same as httpd process owner OR make them globally writable (bad practice).

1. Check apache process owner: `$ps aux | grep httpd`. The first column will be the owner typically it will be `nobody`
2. Change the owner of `images` and `tmp_file_upload` to be become `nobody` or whatever the owner you found in step 1.

   `$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/images/`

   `$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/`
3. Chmod `images` and `tmp_file_upload` now to be writable by the owner, if needed [Seems you already have this in place]. Mentioned in @Dmitry Teplyakov answer.

   `$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/images/`

   `$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/`
4. For more details why this behavior happend, check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir , note that it also talking about `open_basedir` directive.

Comment: More and more hosts run PHP scripts as a normal user via suExec or similar. It's folly to automatically assume the httpd user is required.

Comment: I checked and it is not running as nobody, it is running as the same user that has permissions to all the necessary files